# Android/Ormlite - update only selected fields

Tags: android, sql-update, ormlite

My column definitions for table Shops:

```
@DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, columnName = C_SHOP_ID, index=true, id=true)
private String shopId;

@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.BYTE_ARRAY, canBeNull = false, columnName = C_SHOP_ICON)
private byte[] shopIcon;

@DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, columnName = C_SHOP_DETAILS)
private String shopDetails;

@DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, columnName = C_SHOP_NAME)
private String shopName;

@DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, columnName = C_SHOP_SHORT_DESCRIPTION)
private String shopShorDescription;
```

Next, to perform update (or insert) new row:

```
public void addOrUpdateShop(Shops c)
{
    try
    {
        //getHelper().getShopItemsDao().create(c);
        getHelper().getShopItemsDao().createIfNotExists(c);
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Sometimes, not all fields needs to be changed when performing update. For example, shopDetails or shopIcon (large blob image) should not be updated and leave as is. This is indicated by particular field value. For example, if `c.shopDetails` should not be updated in database, it has value `"no change"`

Now I need to make update row, but every time when c.ShopDetails equals `"no change"`, shopDetails field in my table should not be updated, so field value in table will not be changed. Other fields should be updated though.

Without ormlite, I would need to write all corresponding update queries to exclude some columns from update statement, as it's needed. Is there any simple way to do the same with ormlite (without writing raw sql queries)?

Also, I need to create new row if not exists (so, update builder is not really good for that, since I can only update existing fields with it)

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you need to update the shopeName of the shop object where the shop id is 25.

Then first you need the retrive the Shop object where shop id = 25
Then if there is an such object , Imagine that retrieved Shpops object as oldShopObject.

Now you create new shop object named as newShopObject as follows

```
Shops newShopObject = new Shpos();
newShopObject.shopId = oldShopObject.shopId;
newShopObject.shopIcon = oldShopObject.shopIcon;
newShopObject.shopDetails = oldShopObject.shopDetails;
newShopObject.shopeName = <set your new shop name here>;
newShopObject.shopShortDescription   = oldShopObject.shopShortDescription;
```

Now you can save this newShopObject. 
Update your code as follows and try ,

```
public void addOrUpdateShop(Shops newShopObject)
{
 try
 {
    getHelper().getShopItemsDao().createOrUpdate(newShopObject);
 }
 catch (SQLException e)
 {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```

Read [here](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html)

Comment: Sorry, can you explain it? How to exclude some fields from update and what's the difference with my previous solution?

Comment: Ok, but still update replaces ALL fields in row, with the same values + only one of them (name) with new value. This is not what I want, I want to update only selected field, not replacing others with the same values. Also, I wanto to avoid selecting old object.

Comment: I see, but you cant achieve inserting new record or update a record with same query/code in ormLite. You have to use UpdateBuilder for update a selected field and create() for inserting new record. It might be bit messy, but my solution will bring you both with same set of code lines